# Wordpress woocommerce hooks and ACF in functions.php not working/printing

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, hook-woocommerce

I'm hoping someone can assist with my problem.

I have a WordPress site running WooCommerce and ACF (advanced custom fields).

I'm adding the following code to functions.php...

The `add_action` is the hook into WooCommerce and the rest is pulling data from ACF.

There's no errors but it's simply not printing the various images and URLs. It's just blank.

Am I missing anything obvious?

Here is the code in `functions.php`:

```
add_action('woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'return_policy', 20);

function return_policy() {
// reverse lookup of packages 

    $related_channels = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'select', // name of reverse acf custom field
                'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        )
    ));

    if ($related_channels):
        foreach ($related_channels as $rchannels):
            ?>


            <div class="package-item">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink($rchannels->ID); ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($rchannels->ID); ?>" alt="<?php echo $rchannels->post_title; ?>" title="<?php echo $rchannels->post_title; ?>" ><br> <?php echo $rchannels->post_title; ?>
                </a>
            </div>

            <?php
        endforeach;
    endif;
}
```

Comment: are you sure you have `meta_key` value is **select** and you only have a single int value in corresponding `meta_value`?

Comment: Hi, "select" is correct. And" select" will bring in multiple values. In ACF I'm using the relationship option. The code works when used on a template but not within functions.php.

Comment: pls update you question with a sample value of **select**.